# Android TextView not focus when updating seekbar

Tags: android, textview, seekbar, marquee

I 'm developing an application for Music Player. My Player has a seekbar and a textview to display a song 's name. Because of the song 's name is too long, so i add the marquee to it. But if the seekbar is not update (e.x: pause, stop), the text marquee is working well, and vice versa. Please give me a solution to display the textview marquee and updating seekbar together.
Code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textviewSongName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/textviewSongArtist"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_song_name_size"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:freezesText="true"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    />
```

And the seekbar:

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBarSong"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:maxHeight="10dp" 
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="8dp"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textSongTimeDuration"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textSongTimePlayed"
android:thumb="@drawable/img_seek_handle"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
/>
```

P/s: Sorry for my poor English! :)

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I editted my question: "Please give me a solution to display the textview marquee and updating seekbar together".